# What is the last row of an origin for?

Tags: graphics, matrix

i have the rotation matrix

```
cos  sin  0    0  

-sin cos  0    0

0    0    0    0

0    0    0    1
```

If I were to change the last row to

```
1    1    1    1
```

will it rotate with (1,1,1) as the axis?
If not, what it do, and what does the '1' at row 4 column 4 do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the last row, it will change the 4th coordinate, which in turn will change the x,y,z coordinates of your vector.  The `1` at the bottom right corner simply preserves the 4th coordinate after matrix multiplication.

The 4th coordinate is a "scaling factor" (called the Homogenious coordinate).  It is used for perspective projection.  In short, `(x,y,z,w)` is converted to `(x/w,y/w,z/w)`.

Comment: what does the forth coordinate do?

Comment: I added brief explaination in my answer.